# How to overlay one div over another div

Tags: html, css, position, overlay

I need assistance with overlaying one individual `div` over another individual `div`.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="navi"></div>
<div id="infoi">
    <img src="info_icon2.png" height="20" width="32"/>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I cannot nest the `div#infoi` or the `img`, inside the first `div.navi`.

It has to be two separate `div`s as shown, but I need to know how I could place the `div#infoi` over the `div.navi` and to the right most side and centered on top of the `div.navi`.

Comment: Not the case in this question but if you have one div inside another div the inner div may be fully or partially masked due to `overflow: hidden`, use `overflow: visible` instead.

Answer (score 1588, accepted):

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#navi,
#infoi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#infoi {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navi">a</div>
  <div id="infoi">
    <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" height="20" width="32" />b
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest learning about `position: relative` and child elements with `position: absolute`.

Comment: thanks alex for your help but what I am finding now is that when I resize my window and drag it to be smaller, my info image is not staying with it's parent div. Basically want it to move with the parent div and stay pretty much at the same position even though the screen has been resized somewhat.

Comment: **@tonsils:** The instructions by **alex** should give you the desired result, so there must be something else causing the problem you describe. Could you provide us with a sample of the code (HTML + CSS) so we can help you?

Comment: `absolute`ly positioned elements are positioned relative to their nearest explicitly positioned (`position:absolute|relative|fixed`) parent element. just further clarification ... http://jsfiddle.net/p5jkc8gz/

Comment: Depending on the case, this can be adapted. In my situation I didn't need #navi to be top:0 left:0, and as a general case If you are having HTML code, it's going to be situated as long as the HTML tree is parsed. So maybe in this case that definition is not necessary.

Comment: Adding the in z-index:10; resolved the issue I was having with the textarea being uneditable when other textarea's was not visible. Thank you, Alex.

Answer (score 781):

The accepted solution works great, but IMO lacks an explanation as to why it works. The example below is boiled down to the basics and separates the important CSS from the non-relevant styling CSS. As a bonus, I've also included a detailed explanation of how CSS positioning works.

**TLDR;** if you only want the code, scroll down to **The Result**.

### The Problem

There are two separate, sibling, elements and the goal is to position the second element (with an `id` of `infoi`), so it appears within the previous element (the one with a `class` of `navi`). The HTML structure cannot be changed.

### Proposed Solution

To achieve the desired result we're going to move, or position, the second element, which we'll call `#infoi` so it appears within the first element, which we'll call `.navi`. Specifically, we want `#infoi` to be positioned in the top-right corner of `.navi`.

### CSS Position Required Knowledge

CSS has several properties for positioning elements. By default, all elements are `position: static`. This means the element will be positioned according to its order in the HTML structure, with few exceptions.

The other `position` values are `relative`, `absolute`, `sticky`, and `fixed`. By setting an element's `position` to one of these other values it's now possible to use a combination of the following four properties to position the element:

- `top`
- `right`
- `bottom`
- `left`

In other words, by setting `position: absolute`, we can add `top: 100px` to position the element 100 pixels from the top of the page. Conversely, if we set `bottom: 100px` the element would be positioned 100 pixels from the bottom of the page.

***Here's where many CSS newcomers get lost*** - `position: absolute` has a frame of reference. In the example above, the frame of reference is the `body` element. `position: absolute` with `top: 100px` means the element is positioned 100 pixels from the top of the `body` element.

The position frame of reference, or position context, can be altered by setting the `position` of a parent element to ***any value other than `position: static`***. That is, we can create a new position context by giving a parent element:

- `position: relative;`
- `position: absolute;`
- `position: sticky;`
- `position: fixed;`

For example, if a `<div class="parent">` element is given `position: relative`, any child elements use the `<div class="parent">` as their position context. If a child element were given `position: absolute` and `top: 100px`, the element would be positioned 100 pixels from the top of the `<div class="parent">` element, because the `<div class="parent">` is now the position context.

**The other factor** to be aware of is **stack order** - or how elements are stacked in the z-direction. The must-know here is the stack order of elements are, by default, defined by the reverse of their order in the HTML structure. Consider the following example:

```
<body>
  <div>Bottom</div>
  <div>Top</div>
</body>
```

In this example, if the two `<div>` elements were positioned in the same place on the page, the `<div>Top</div>` element would cover the `<div>Bottom</div>` element. Since `<div>Top</div>` comes after `<div>Bottom</div>` in the HTML structure it has a higher stacking order.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#bottom {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

#top {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
<div id="top">Top</div>
```

The stacking order can be changed with CSS using the `z-index` or `order` properties.

We can ignore the stacking order in this issue as the natural HTML structure of the elements means the element we want to appear on `top` comes after the other element.

So, back to the problem at hand - we'll use position context to solve this issue.

### The Solution

As stated above, our goal is to position the `#infoi` element so it appears within the `.navi` element. To do this, we'll wrap the `.navi` and `#infoi` elements in a new element `<div class="wrapper">` so we can create a new position context.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navi"></div>
  <div id="infoi"></div>
</div>
```

Then create a new position context by giving `.wrapper` a `position: relative`.

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

With this new position context, we can position `#infoi` within `.wrapper`.  First, give `#infoi` a `position: absolute`, allowing us to position `#infoi` absolutely in `.wrapper`.

Then add `top: 0` and `right: 0` to position the `#infoi` element in the top-right corner. Remember, because the `#infoi` element is using `.wrapper` as its position context, it will be in the top-right of the `.wrapper` element.

```
#infoi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Because `.wrapper` is merely a container for `.navi`, positioning `#infoi` in the top-right corner of `.wrapper` gives the effect of being positioned in the top-right corner of `.navi`.

And there we have it, `#infoi` now appears to be in the top-right corner of `.navi`.

### The Result

The example below is boiled down to the basics, and contains some minimal styling.

```css
/*
*  position: relative gives a new position context
*/
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

/*
*  The .navi properties are for styling only
*  These properties can be changed or removed
*/
.navi {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 40px;
}


/*
*  Position the #infoi element in the top-right
*  of the .wrapper element
*/
#infoi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  /*
  *  Styling only, the below can be changed or removed
  *  depending on your use case
  */
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navi"></div>
  <div id="infoi">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x20/000000/ffffff?text=?" height="20" width="32"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

### An Alternate (Grid) Solution

Here's an alternate solution using CSS Grid to position the `.navi` element with the `#infoi` element in the far right. I've used the verbose `grid` properties to make it as clear as possible.

```css
:root {
  --columns: 12;
}

/*
*  Setup the wrapper as a Grid element, with 12 columns, 1 row
*/
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
}

/*
*  Position the .navi element to span all columns
*/
.navi {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span var(--columns);
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  
  /*
  *  Styling only, the below can be changed or removed
  *  depending on your use case
  */
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}


/*
*  Position the #infoi element in the last column, and center it
*/
#infoi {
  grid-column-start: var(--columns);
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  place-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navi"></div>
  <div id="infoi">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x20/000000/ffffff?text=?" height="20" width="32"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

### An Alternate (No Wrapper) Solution

In the case we can't edit any HTML, meaning we can't add a wrapper element, we can still achieve the desired effect.

Instead of using `position: absolute` on the `#infoi` element, we'll use `position: relative`. This allows us to reposition the `#infoi` element from its default position below the `.navi` element. With `position: relative` we can use a negative `top` value to move it up from its default position, and a `left` value of `100%` minus a few pixels, using `left: calc(100% - 52px)`, to position it near the right-side.

```css
/*
*  The .navi properties are for styling only
*  These properties can be changed or removed
*/
.navi {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*
*  Position the #infoi element in the top-right
*  of the .wrapper element
*/
#infoi {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -40px;
  left: calc(100% - 52px);

  /*
  *  Styling only, the below can be changed or removed
  *  depending on your use case
  */
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi"></div>
<div id="infoi">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x20/000000/ffffff?text=?" height="20" width="32"/>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the most useful entry IMO because it explains why it works!

Comment: Basically use `position:relative` on the parent div and `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` on the child div.

Comment: I had no idea that `position : relative` was intended to modify the behaviour of the children. This is such a great answer, thanks! :D

Comment: Would this approach still work if the parent div (.wrapper in your example) was laid out via flexbox rules?

Comment: @Jools While it could be made to work with flexbox, I don't believe it's an ideal solution. CSS Grid on the other hand is a great option. I have updated the solution above with an example using CSS Grid.

Comment: Brilliant answer, which helped me understand where I was going wrong.  Only thing I would be tempted to add, would be a scenario that covers this in the context of elements that need to scroll with their parents.  (Which this answer helped me get to!).

Comment: thank you very much @BrettDeWoody, now i know more!

Answer (score 183):

The new **Grid CSS** specification provides a far more elegant solution. Using `position: absolute` may lead to overlaps or scaling issues while Grid will save you from dirty CSS hacks.

Most minimal Grid Overlay example:

*HTML*

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is the content</div>
  <div class="overlay">Overlay - must be placed after content in the HTML</div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.content, .overlay {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}
```

That's it. If you don't build for Internet Explorer, your code will most probably work.

Comment: Definitely, as well because this works like a charm when you want the overlapping dive being behind (in my case I have a coloured table acting as background).

Comment: This is the best 0 hack answer and MUST be promoted everywhere. We (web developers) tend to over-engineer so many things, and never try to simplify those for decades..... Burying and sinking in unnecessary accidental complexity to take the paycheck. Have some self-respect, colleagues ;-) <3 Your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 144):

By using a `div` with style `z-index:1;` and `position: absolute;` you can overlay your `div` on any other `div`.

`z-index` determines the order in which divs 'stack'. A div with a higher `z-index` will appear in front of a div with a lower `z-index`. Note that this property **only works with positioned elements**.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: The note about positioned elements is critical.

Comment: This answer is so incomplete that it needs a whole post to explain why. Look up stacking contexts.

Comment: Adding position and z-index helped me. Didn't know z-index only works with positions.

Answer (score 51):

### You need to add a parent with a `relative position`, inside this parent you can set the `absolute position` of your divs

```
<div> <------Relative
  <div/> <------Absolute
  <div/> <------Absolute
  <div/> <------Absolute
<div/>
```

**Final result:**

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/XWKYEYb?editors=0100

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">TOP: I am at Top & above of body container</div>
  
    <div class="center">CENTER: I am at Top & in Center of body container</div>
  
  <div class="footer">BOTTOM: I am at Bottom & above of body container</div>
</div>
```

Set HTML Body full width

```
 html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

After that, you can set a div with the relative position to take full width and height

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/5591663/pexels-photo-5591663.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Inside this div with the relative position you can put your div with absolute positions

**On TOP above the container**

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: #d81b60 ;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:15px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

**On BOTTOM above the container**

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:15px;
  padding:10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;

}
```

**In CENTER above the container**

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  left:  30%;
  right: 30%;
  bottom:30%;
  top: 30%;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Here follows a simple solution 100% based on CSS. The "secret" is to use the `display: inline-block` in the wrapper element. The `vertical-align: bottom` in the image is a hack to overcome the 4px padding that some browsers add after the element.

**Advice**: if the element before the wrapper is inline they can end up nested. In this case you can "wrap the wrapper" inside a container with `display: block` - usually a good and old `div`.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0);
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.hover:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8);
    // You can tweak with other background properties too (ie: background-image)...
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hover"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 26):

This is what you need:

```js
function showFrontLayer() {
  document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='visible';
}
function hideFrontLayer() {
  document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

```css
#bg_mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 981px;
  height: 610px;
  background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
} 

#frontlayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 70px 140px 175px 140px;
  padding : 30px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
} 


</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="test.html">
      <div id="baselayer">

        <input type="text" value="testing text"/>
        <input type="button" value="Show front layer" onclick="showFrontLayer();"/> Click 'Show front layer' button<br/><br/><br/>

        Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
        Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
        Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing textsting text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
        <div id="bg_mask">
          <div id="frontlayer"><br/><br/>
            Now try to click on "Show front layer" button or the text box. It is not active.<br/><br/><br/>
            Use position: absolute to get the one div on top of another div.<br/><br/><br/>
            The bg_mask div is between baselayer and front layer.<br/><br/><br/>
            In bg_mask, img_dot_white.jpg(1 pixel in width and height) is used as background image to avoid IE browser transparency issue;<br/><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Hide front layer" onclick="hideFrontLayer();"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

I am not much of a coder nor an expert in CSS, but I am still using your idea in my web designs. I have tried different resolutions too:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 901px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: url(images/wrapperback.gif);
  color: #000;
}
#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100.00%;
  height: 122px;
  background-color: #00314e;
  background-image: url(images/header.jpg);
  color: #fff;
}
#menu {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 495px;
  width: 390px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
      menu will go here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course there will be a wrapper around both of them. You can control the location of the menu div which will be displayed within the header div with left margins and top positions. You can also set the div menu to float right if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to bring an overlay effect with a loading icon over another div.

```
<style>
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: black url('icons/loading.gif') center center no-repeat; /* Make sure the path and a fine named 'loading.gif' is there */
        background-size: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: .6;
    }
    .wraper{
        position: relative;
        width:400px;  /* Just for testing, remove width and height if you have content inside this div */
        height:500px; /* Remove this if you have content inside */
    }
</style>

<h2>The overlay tester</h2>
<div class="wraper">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <h3>Apply the overlay over this div</h3>
</div>
```

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/fotozolucu/edit?html,css,output