# jquery css overlay div over another div?

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to find to overlay a div over another then i found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

But this doesnt seems to works for me ?

I just want it something like :

```
<div>The div below</div>
<div>OverLay div</div>
```

Can u please give me a working demo ?

Comment: What CSS have you tried? That example is pretty basic and should work for what you want.

Comment: When i tried to make the overlay div it either goes up or down

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/J9bjm/

The only thing you need to grasp from it is the `position: absolute;` and the `top: 0;` (or however far away from the top of the page that you want it)

Comment: Doesnt the overlay div goes a bit up ?

Comment: @kritya -- thats only because the css has not been reset. one minute

Comment: @kritya -- check the fiddle now (jsfiddle applied some default padding which i removed)

Comment: @This should do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/J9bjm/12/ The reason it goes up is because `position:absolute; top:0` positions it from the top of the window. If the overlay div were child of a relatively positioned div it would be 0px from the top of that div. That's why you sometimes need to explicitly play with the math. I've moved it `top:-62px` = 50px for height, (5 * 2)px for padding and (1 *2) px for the borders

Comment: @Nupul -- no math needed. jsfiddle had some default padding which i removed.

Comment: ...and Neal just showed it by adjusting body's padding/margin :) another way

Comment: @Nupul -- it is default for jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The first answer seems good to me, but here is a link to the <s>[w3schools css position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)</s> page.  The "try it yourself" is a convenient sandbox.

Edit: as noted in the comment, w3schools is not a good reference.  I marked the link with strikethrough, but left it live.

Comment: @neal LOL this site. How do u reach there ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that might work in your particular case, using negative margin instad of position:

```
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>

#one, #two, #three, #four {
    background: #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#two {
    background: #aaa;
    margin-left: 10px; /* Set to 0 for complete overlap */
    margin-top: -80px; /* Set to -100 for complete overlap */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xatpf/

Comment: margins? why not use `position`?

Comment: My answer could be useful because if the questioner is trying to overlap one single `<div>` over another, using `margin` instead of `position` can be a simpler solution (depending on the implementation, which we know nothing about)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the structure of your HTML, you probably don't even need jquery to do this. If you know exactly where you want them to be in the window you can use the `position: absolute;` CSS on them both. [This page](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) explains pretty well how to use the `position` CSS attribute in different ways to position divs pretty much however you may like.

EDIT: I edited the fiddle with

```
body{
padding:0px;
}
```

To make them line up at the top, the window by default has some padding which affects anything that's not on `position: absolute;`