# How can you fade to a new background without the content fading in as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change my page's background when it goes to a new page by fading the new image in slowly behind the content of the page. However, when I try to fade in the new image, literally the whole page fades in because the div containing the background also contains the content. The div that contains the background image change is "nextImage".

```
<body>
<div id="nextImage">
     Bunch of Content
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript I'm trying to get working which is on a new page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nextImage').css('background-image', 'url(Tranquil.jpg)').hide();
    $('#nextImage').fadeIn(5000);
</script>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body 
{
    background-image:url("abstract1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:font-family: Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#nextImage
{
    background-image="";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:font-family: Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've basically answered your own question by saying `the div containing the background also contains the content`

Separate the background div and content div so that you can fade the background as needed without affecting the content

```
<body>
   <div id="nextImage">
   </div>
   <div id="content">
       Bunch of Content
   </div>
</body>
```

check out my example here http://jsfiddle.net/Hn9w4/

Comment: That doesn't work because the background appears on top of the page. Not to mention you have to use javscript to adjust the height of nextImage to the height of body.

Comment: all you need to do is put `position:absolute;` on your background div

Comment: well.. that kept it in one place but now it just fades in and covers up the content.

Comment: @GavinSellers check out my example i've added on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use two overlayed divs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) and the fade the one with the background.

Comment: You can use two overlayed divs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) and fade the one with the background.