# Street view API 3 (add custom minimap) close button Street view and Pegman

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

In my script, when you drop the pegman on to the map, it loads Street View with a custom minimap. You can see the minimap with the pegman and move it for Street View, and it works fine.

However, when you click the close button on the street view, the minimap and Street View close fine but the pegman doesn't return to its default position. It stays on the map, and can't be re-dropped.

I want to move the pegman back to default position when Street View is closed, and if you drop it on map again to load Street View like the first time.

**online code** http://jsbin.com/ayejim/edit#preview

This is my function `initialize`:

```
    function initialize() {
var lifestyle = [{}];
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: CITY_MAP_ZOOMING_FACT,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(CITY_MAP_CENTER_LAT, CITY_MAP_CENTER_LNG),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo $maptype;?>

  }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
   map.setOptions({styles: lifestyle});

    /////////////////////////////
    var g = google.maps;
    var pano, mini;
    var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    pano = map.getStreetView();


  /** Listen to panorama's visibility changes to detect
  * when pegman is dropped onto the map
  * and when Street view is closed
  */

  g.event.addListener(pano, "visible_changed", function() {
   // Street view activated by dropping pegman
   if (!mini && pano.getVisible()) {
    // Container for mini map and close button

    var c = document.createElement("div");
    c.id = "minimap";
    c.style.visibility = "visible";

    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = "closebutton";
    d.onclick = function() {
    // Toggles button icon and moves copyright notice
     var terms = document.getElementById("note");
//    var terms = mapdiv.childNodes[1].childNodes[2];
      if (c.style.visibility == "visible") {
        c.style.visibility = "hidden";
        d.className = "closed";
        terms.style.marginRight = "24px";
      }
      else {
       c.style.visibility = "visible";
       d.className = "";
       terms.style.marginRight = "170px";
      }
    };

    c.appendChild(d);
    mapdiv.appendChild(c);
    mapdiv.appendChild(d);

    mini = new g.Map(c, {
      center: pano.getPosition(),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: "roadmap",
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      streetView: pano,
      styles: lifestyle

    });

    /** Moves the 'Terms' notice to the left
    * to ensure it's not covered up.
    * There are two such notices in the document.
    * Make sure to catch the right ones.
    */
    g.event.addListener(mini, "tilesloaded", function() {
     var terms = mini.getDiv().firstChild.childNodes[2];
     terms.style.marginRight = "24px";
     var sv_terms = mapdiv.childNodes[1].childNodes[2];
     sv_terms.id = "note";
     sv_terms.style.marginRight = "170px";
     sv_terms.style.zIndex = "1";
   });
    // Binds mini map's center to pano position
    mini.bindTo("center", pano, "position");

    // Street view finished by click on Street view close button
   } else if (mini instanceof g.Map && !pano.getVisible()) {
     mapdiv.removeChild(document.getElementById("minimap"));
    **//initialize(); if try call initialize again pegman back default position but map back to default position too like the first time.and markers hide , i don't know why this happens**
   }
 });
 /////////////////////////
   mgr = new MarkerManager( map );
   google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
      if (markers) {
         for (var level in markers) {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener( document.getElementById( level ), 'click', function() {
               setCategoryVisiblity( this.id, this.checked );
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < markers[level].length; i++) {

               var details = markers[level][i];
               var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(details.icons,new google.maps.Size(PIN_POINT_ICON_WIDTH, PIN_POINT_ICON_HEIGHT));
               var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(details.location[0], details.location[1]);
               <?php if(get_current_city_set_zooming_opt() == '1') { ?>
                 multimarkerdata[i]  = new google.maps.LatLng(details.location[0], details.location[1]);
               <?php } ?>
               markers[level][i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                  title: details.name,
                  position: myLatLng,
                  icon: image,
                  clickable: true,
                  draggable: false,
                  flat: true,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
               });


            attachMessage(markers[level][i], details.message);
            }
            mgr.addMarkers( markers[level], 0 );
         }
          <?php if(get_current_city_set_zooming_opt() == '1') { ?>
             var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for ( var j = 0; j < multimarkerdata.length; j++ )
                {
                 latlngbounds.extend( multimarkerdata[ j ] );
                }
               map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );
          <?php } ?>
         mgr.refresh();
      }
   });

    // but that message is not within the marker's instance data 
    function attachMessage(marker, msg) {
      var myEventListener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (pano.getVisible()) { 
        infowindow.open(pano, marker); 
      } else { 
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
          { content: String(msg) 
          });
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 
      } 
         if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
          { content: String(msg) 
          });
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: It's a nice concept, I tried some ideas I found Googling "sticky pegman" and "pegman reset", in particular manually setting `map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);`. It didn't work :( The least I can do is leave a running "demo" for others to see and try to solve your question. What you have to do is place the pegman, close the Street View, and after returning to the map, notice how the pegman is "disabled", moving it won't reopen a new Street View, and you can't put him back in his starting place. **DEMO HERE** http://jsbin.com/ayejim/edit#preview

Comment: thank you Liliana, I add Demo in the post, i wish that someone  can help me,  the concept is nice like you says

Comment: look at this Liliana, http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/fubNj/7/ this demo use setVisible(false) and when you drop pegman to default spot street view stop too but I can't make it work in my script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not entirely sure why the current code is not working, but I'm also a little skeptic on the approach you're taking in the current code. Why not make a separate div for the panorama (streetview) and do some styling to the map_canvas div to replicate your current method (instead of using the minimap div). I've created a basis in this jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/FnrbX/embedded/result/ and http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/FnrbX/ for source code) that you can check out and possible use as a foundation for your solution.

Allow me to walk you through my code - with a little bit of looking into the streetView class properties and jquery I'm sure your question could be solved.

```
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="container">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="bigmap"></div>
  <div id="pano" class="bigmap" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

first thing is first, in the mark-up we want to declare a div for the map and a div for the panorama, which will be bound to the map. We declare it in a container for styling purposes (when we want to overlap the map over the panorama). Notice the style of the panorama is initially set to `display:none` otherwise you'll be seeing a grayed out region (which is the pano without any location data because the pegman is not set).

```
#container {
  width: 940px;
  height: 640px;
  position: relative;
}
#map_canvas, 
#pano {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#map_canvas {
  z-index: 10;
}
.bigmap{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.minimap{
  width:480px;
  height:320px;
}
```

The styling here is essentially set to make it possible for the map_canvas div to overlap over the pano div when the pegman gets dropped. I used the concept from this solution for div overlapping ( [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)). The .minimap and .bigmap classes make it easy to switch the map_canvas from one view to another, which will make more sense in the javascript section below.

```
function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    enableCloseButton : true,
    visible: false
  };
  var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetView : panorama
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

up to this point in the javascript we initialize all the map contents. it is pretty self explanatory, to look into the properties that are set in here have a look at the google maps api v3 reference - i found it to be very useful.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "visible_changed", function() {
    if (panorama.getVisible() && $("#pano").is(':visible')){
        //moving the pegman around the map
    }else if(panorama.getVisible() && $("#pano").is(':hidden')){
        $("#pano").show();          
        $("#map_canvas").removeClass('bigmap');
        $("#map_canvas").addClass('minimap');
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "closeclick", function() {
        $("#pano").hide();  
        $("#map_canvas").removeClass('minimap');
        $("#map_canvas").addClass('bigmap');        
    });
  });        
}
```

Note: the event listeners are still declared in the initialize() function. But essentially we listen for a change in the panorama visibility, but that alone is not enough to determine if there is actual data in the pano div element. Remember when we set the pano div display to none, well we can use jquery to check for the visibility. If it's visible, that means it is NOT the initial drop of the pegman - if it's hidden then that's where we change the class of the map_canvas to minimap. Also note that we listen for the closeclick in the "visible_changed" listener. This is because visible_changed also includes the closeclick action, so by putting it inside we're binding the listener to the other. Once the closeclick is triggered, we hide the pano div and change the map_canvas back to it's normal size.

The great thing about this approach is the native "closeclick" action on the streetView removes the pegman from the map it's set to and returns it back to normal (which is what you wanted in your problem). Also, to go back to your original position you can simply do a `map.panTo()` on the "closeclick" event listener to the initial location.

I hope this what you were looking for, if it's far off then my apologies! I know it's essentially asking you to redesign your current code structure - but just thought this approach was much simpler and seems to do the same thing you want done.

Comment: There's some good stuff here. +1. However you may need to ensure that the API knows the map is resized when things are hidden and redisplayed, by explicitly triggering the `resize` event. (Or it may simply be an artifact in using jsFiddle, but at the moment your example doesn't get the resized map to display correctly)

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. I found the map was getting cut off if I dropped the pegman out of the 480x320 viewport. But calling the resize event might do the trick.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the answer :) I "enhanced" it here http://jsbin.com/olayiw/edit#preview  The goal was for closer behavior to what Gustavo had (such as centered pegman) and made sure most of the usability was clean, for example, placing the pegman in the river would revert to the large map. I could not figure out how to achieve this result when the pegman is placed in his holding spot, however.

Comment: those are some nice enhancements indeed, the jsbin demo looks great! not sure what problems ur encountering though, can u elaborate on the issue ur facing?

Comment: @Suvi The behavior is unpredictable. What I'm trying to accomplish, is that when the Pegman is dragged back to his little original rectangle (on the top left corner of the mini-map), the street view should turn off and the large roadmap restored. Sometimes this does happen, other times, Pegman is placed on the street behind the control, and sometimes he stays put in his rectangle but the roadmap does not enlarge. It is a minor detail, but I have no clue where to update the code.

Comment: @Lilina that is quite the strange behavior. I've tried looking through the reference but couldn't find any event that's related to putting the pegman back in his place. You could potentially find the CSS behind the pegman and use jquery to detect if the object is on the map or not - but this will be extremely time consuming and tedious. Took my a good half hour to just figure out that google uses a "sprite" image and positioning to select which pegman image to use: http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/cb/mod_cb_scout/cb_scout_sprite_api_003.png

Comment: Wow, "sprite" never appeared in my research. You've done excellent work already with your answer! Maybe a +500 bounty will put my Pegman in his place :) (Now I need to start incorporating the Pegman as my custom icon. Great find!)

Comment: Thank you and i would definitely encourage you to test your luck with that +500 bounty offer :)..however it is very tricky work though, because Google doesn't give any IDs or classes for the elements they use (i think it's just rendered through their javascript without the need for it) - so you'll have to do some hacking around.

Comment: Thank you Suvi, I sensed it was a bad use of div. I made ​​it work in my script, however there is any conflict with jquery lib versions or something. You code work when add ajax jquery min 1.7.2 but my script jQuery mega menu breaks and if not add JQ1.7.2 google chrome say **uncaught typeerror property '$' of object [object Window] is nor a function]** other information is that my script use a jQuery v1.7.1. and I'm not familiar with these issues.Anyway apart from... you script works very well, maybe this is another question I present to open

Comment: I fixed this conflict with other script menu and now work both

Comment: I fixed too the center position and resize adding `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.panTo(panorama.getPosition());` Thank you Lilina

Comment: I was looking for this event: `closeclick`, quite some time now! Thanks man!