# how to access link, which is inside div and if div is overlay of another div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to design a layout, on which I want to put one div into another. But, the problem is link of the back div is not working.

```
<div id="container" style="z-index:-10;position:relative;height:100px">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>
</div>
<div id="container1" style="margin-top:10px">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>
</div>
```

which means, if I'm trying to access link of div id `container`, then I can't. How to solve this problem.

**Note :** I can't remove z-index, because I want `container1` above of `container`

Comment: can you try and upload a proper working fiddle with styles? With the current markup you can't achieve, probably need a different approach

Comment: you see this http://jsfiddle.net/aAydX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Parse has got it right.

Without knowing what context you are using it in, just remove `z-index:-10` or change it to a positive value like `z-index:1;`.

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;height:100px;">
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>
</div>
<div id="container1" style="margin-top:10px;">
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>
</div>
```

Edit:

I just realised that you said that you wanted to put one div *into* another. That would be done like this:

```
<div id="container" style="z-index:1;position:relative;height:100px;background-color:#eee;">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>

    <div id="container1" style="margin-top:10px;background-color:#ddd;">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div">StackOverflow1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put some `background-color` on the divs to make it clearer.

Comment: you can simply understand like.. i need floating menu. But, the current problem is, menu is currently showing back of `container`. But, I want opposite of it. But, in this case link of `container` is not working

Comment: I can't put one div inside another.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you can't. Because the parent container already been set to `z-index:-10`, so the child can't have the z-index value higher than that. Maybe you can try change a bit the markup like this one, since you have applied `position:relative` at the `container` div there

```
<a href="#" style="position:absolute;left:0;">StackOverflow1</a>
<div id="container" style="z-index:-10;position:relative;height:100px"></div>
<div id="container1" style="margin-top:10px">
    <a href="#">StackOverflow1</a>
</div>
```

Add `position:absolute`, so the link act like it is inside the parent container with the lower z-index and of course it is accessible. You can see your updated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gyheE/2/