# How to put div over another?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a div that stand for the logo, and I have another div that stand for a slide show.
The slide show div is under the logo div, and I want it to be under the it and behind it.

This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
  <div id="site-container">
    <div id="header-container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="slide"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
   background:url(img/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:259px;
   height:147px;
   float:left;
}

#slide {
   background:url(img/slide.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:776px;
   height:437px;
   float:left;
}
```

I tried to use z position, but it turns to be something I dont want it to.
Any why to make the logo div be a top layer without moving its correct position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overlay one div over another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Answer (score 4):

If you want it over top of the div, you have to use `z-index`. You have to convert your `#logo` and `#slide` to have a `position` attribute and `z-index` should be applied to the div whose position you want to move up or down.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:
  CSS

```
  #Behind{
    width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    padding:50px;
   }
  #TopOne{ 
    position: absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:50px;
    background-color:wheat;
    padding:20px; 
    }
```

and the htm simply

```
    <div id="Behind"></div>
    <div id="TopOne">This is Just Testing :)</div>
```

This is the JSFiddle link also  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adelassi/wC36D/1/)

Answer (score 3):

The corrected css is,

```
 #logo {
   background:url(img/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:259px;
   height:147px;
   float:left;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1000;
}

#slide {
   background:url(img/slide.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:776px;
   height:437px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   z-index:500;
}
```

The position of the slide div is set as relative and logo div is set as absolute. So the logo is placed within the slide.

The value of z-index attribute decides which one is under.

Comment: z-index should be an integer, not pixels

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quite a few things to do that.

**z-index** will tell you what comes on top.

**position** needs to be *absolute*

And you may what to play with the margins...

Answer (score 1):

i used these:

```
#logo {
   background:url(img/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:259px;
   height:147px;
   float:left;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
}

#slide {
   background:url(img/slide.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:776px;
   height:437px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
}
```

and the slide show is now when it should be but the logo div float to the right while i need it to stay at the left side...
sorry if you dont understand not sure about my english grammer lol

Comment: Instead of providing ua updates as answer.. U can jus update your question.. I have done it this time.. :)