# Jquery sliding form border

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had achieved the sliding form using `jquery` but when i click on the link, i wish to have a form border like this:

But when i am putting a border for both it is looking like separate borders.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By25CEM_KEOiWU42SFhsaTVmZWc/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code :

http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/MgcDU/8360/

But i am not able to achieve this kind of border effect which surrounds the link & the form.

Please help me.

Comment: What's your HTML, CSS and JS look like so far?

Comment: can you make it more clear?

Comment: It sounds like he's asking for a border to surround the `Add` button and the form once he clicks the button - right now there are 2 separate borders.

Comment: O.M.G. Comic sans! I fixed your indents http://jsfiddle.net/n8rq7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I changed the #add click function of your jQuery script like this: [added css to the u286 id, then remove it later]

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    if ($('#sliding-form').is(":hidden")) {
        $('#sliding-form').slideDown('slow');
        $('#u286').css({
            'border':'1px solid #000',
            'border-bottom-color':'white'
        });
    } else {
        $('#sliding-form').slideUp('slow');
        $('#u286').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** I changed a bit around in your css file. I overlaid the `#bottom-header` div on top of the `#sliding-form` div to make sure there is that white gap. Here is what I changed:

1. Added `position: relative;` to the `.container` class,
2. Added `#bottom-header {    position: absolute;    z-index:10;}`,
3. Added `background:#fff;` to `#u286`,
4. Removed `.mouseOver {background:#fff;}` Since it doesn't affect anything,
5. Changed `top: 30px;` to `top: 26px;` in `#sliding-form`.

Hopefully this is more to your liking!

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8362/)

[Useful StackOverflow question / answer on overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Comment: Yes it helped but it was not was i am trying to achieve. Did You see in stackoverflow the three tabs `active`, `oldest`, `votes`, how the border coming around them, i want something like this. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Good call! I edited my post - hopefully this is more like what you were looking for!