# set delay in jQuery AJAX call on clicking of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below code, it executes when I click on a button.

I need to display a progress bar/waiting image in the browser for 5 seconds, when user clicks on a button. How to set time out and how to display progress bar/waiting page image in the page when user clicks on a button

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
var formData = $("form").serialize();           
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cgi-bin/config',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;           
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);  
    },
    failure: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed!!!");
    },error: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
    }           
  });       
});
```

Comment: do you need that to annoy your users? :)

Comment: I too felt the same, but its there in the requirement :)

Comment: How do you plan to show that *progress bar*? Using an UI lib or what?

Comment: No UI libs, need to use just jquery and css

Comment: Nice but you didn't answered how you plan to show that progress bar...

Comment: i too dont have idea how to display an progress bar image :( that's the reason i am posting :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Use **beforeSend**  and  **complete**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var formData = $("form").serialize();           
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cgi-bin/config',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;           
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);  
    },
    failure: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed!!!");
    },error: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
    },  
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.progress').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
      $('.progress').hide();
    }         
  });     
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress" style="display:none;"><img src="loading.gif" />Loading...</div>
```

Comment: WTH? This wont even run! You'll got a syntax error.

Comment: this will just for before sending, but i need to set time out..
and i need to display the progress image in the middle of the browser

Comment: @sree I think you need to hide progress image after ajax request is completed,right?

Comment: yes i need to set the progress image in MIDDLE of the browser before sending request (like displaying processing request) and need to hide progress image once the ajax request is completed

Comment: @sree,I updated my answer,you need to add css for .progress,Hope it will work

Comment: @shijin, 

i need to set time out..
and is that loading.gif will displays in middle of the browser? where exactly i need to set the div?

Comment: @sree have you got the answer?I see your comments now,because of day off

Comment: @shijin No i didn't get any solution:(

Comment: @sree Can you try to style .progress like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div

Comment: @shijin i have tried that div and your ajax before send and after send
 The loading.jpg is displaying always , its not should be right? I need to display after clicking of the button, and need to hide it see my full code here 

        #container {
    
        width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position: relative;
}


 <div id="container">
   
 <img src="loading.jpg" height="20" width="32"/>
</div>

Comment: @shijin , yes its not working but i could able to fix my code with the  link   http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/Qw6uv/4/ , this works fine..anyways thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var startTime = Date.now(),
  // finish function is called at the end - when request is completed and at least 5s passed
  // result will be null on error or whatever was received by success callback
  finish = function (result) {
    if (result === null) {
      // probably error, handle it..
    } else {
      // handle result
    }
    $('#progress').hide();
  },
  checkDone = function (result) {
    var r = Date.now() - startTime; // time taken by request
    if (r < 5000) { // if less than 5s then set timeout for remaining time
      setTimeout(function () {
        finish(result);
      }, 5000 - r);
    } else { // if there was already 5s finish immediately
      finish(result);
    }
  },
  formData = $("form").serialize();
  $('#progress').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cgi-bin/config',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      checkDone(result);
    },
    failure: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed!!!");
      checkDone(null);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Ajax request failed to update data!!!");
      checkDone(null);
    }
  });     
});
```

progress div example (just put in body):

```
<div id="progress" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:99999;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;opcity:0.7;background:url('/img/progress.gif') 50% 50% no-repeate #000"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could able to fix my code with the link jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/Qw6uv/4 , this works fine..