# how to place one div on top of another, when both are centered using auto margin?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, a `square` and a `bar`. Both are centered using `auto` margin. But I want to place bar over square. How can I do this?

html

```
<div class="square">square</div>
<div class="bar">square</div>
```

css

```
.square,.bar{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
.square{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bar{
    background-color:green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/P9yWK/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: you can't even change the HTML code?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P9yWK/1/?

Comment: I supposed this was what you want http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/P9yWK/3/

Comment: @KingKing the bar should cover square..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/atomicrevolution/P9yWK/5/

Is this what you mean?

```
.square,.bar{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.square{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.bar{
    background-color:green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/mz6rk/**

I made `position:relative` and placed the bar at `-square_height/2 - bar_height/2`

This does assume you know the height of both the square and bar though, I don't know if that's always the case..

**UPDATE:**
Actually, only the bar needs to have `position:relative` (I put it on both in the fiddle).