# Can't get div to overlay on top of other div

Tags: css

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="image-container" >    
  <div class="image-overlay">
     dsfsadfdsafjhjkdhfkjashflksadhjfklasdjhfklsjdkfhasdjkhfsjkhdjkfs
  </div>                                  
  <div class="img-user">
    <img src="/images/flandre.jpg" width="220" />
  </div> 
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;    
}

.img-user, .img-overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 10;
}
```

But `<div class="image-overlay">` appears underneath `<div class="img-user">`.

I'm trying to follow the example in the top answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div), and it seems like I'm doing everything similar, but it's not working.

Comment: Use a lower z-index for the img-user.

Comment: Using a lower z-index for img-user won't do anything. Having no z-index asigned means having a z-index of 0, so it won't make a difference @jacelysh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your classes.

You're writing img-overlay in your css.

You're using image-overlay in your html.

Comment: Oh Lord. This always happens when I learn something new I think I'm doing something semantically wrong when I just have stupid typos.

Comment: Tis' programming. Fuctions for everyone.