# How to overlay polymer flex div

Tags: html, css, polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

I'm using [polymer-shadow styles](https://github.com/Polymer/layout/blob/master/shadow-layout.html) to use flex divs.
I've follow [these answers on How to overlay div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div). But, as soon as I set a 'flexed' div with absolute position, everything is chaos.

I did [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NfsTN0?p=preview) where you can reproduce it.

My code looks like:

```html
<div class="layout horizontal">
    <div class="flex" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="flex-5">
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <!--Following two divs should be overlayed-->
        <div style="background-color:papayawhip">---------------</div>
        <div class="content">Data</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If I use position relative/absolute out of shadow-dom flex classes, it works properly:

```html
  <div>
    <div style="background-color:papayawhip; position:absolute">---------------</div>
    <div class="content" style="position:absolute">Data</div>
  </div>
```

So, how can I overlay one div above another, when both are inside a flex container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make your `flex-5` `div` `relative` and the two inner `div`s `fit`.

```
<div class="flex-5 relative">
    <div class="fit" style="background-color:papayawhip">---------------</div>
    <div class="fit">Data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see this updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUoBkwTp4U0XnMue5K6a?p=preview).

Note that in Polymer, `<div class="relative"></div>` is the same as

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
```

`<div class="fit"></div>` is the same as

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```