# Using JavaScript, how can I replace my div tag text, for every new button I click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program which has 5 buttons. Each button displays a different table.

As of now, when I click the first button...the corresponding table for button1 appears. Which is good!

However, when I click the next button (button 2)..the NEW table appears right under the old.

How can I replace the old table with the new? Rather than having it appear below the old one in a stacked fashion.

Comment: How do you expect someone to tell you what's wrong with your code if you haven't shared your code?

Comment: Can you please add some  code or provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overlay divs using CSS, here's some way to do it :

[How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

But keep in mind the order, if you need to hide and show interactively you may need javascript.

Here's is an approach, but you must first assign a class for each button and an ID to every div :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.class_for_your_button', function () {
        $('#your_div_id' ).toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps my friend !

Comment: Yes, I want to know the js because it needs to be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the click handler's already managed, all you need to do to replace the html in the div rather than appending it, from within the click handler.

To do this you need to grab the div element, and then use innerHtml to change it, heres an example:

```
document.getElementById("divId").innerHtml = "<table></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your adding the new table without clearing the first one from the container or or hiding it

Comment: One way is to replace the inner html of the container like @Matt M mentioned in his answer , it would be better if you provide your code so we can help you more