# set div over another Div css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a web app and I want to open a modal on a button click of `sidenav bar` but the modal is opening behind the `sidenav bar`. I tried `absolute` and `relative` positioning but it's not working either.

sidenav bar

```
<div class="left-nav clearfix" style="background-color:#00859d; position:relative;">
```

modal

```
 <div class="container" style="width:100%; margin-left:30%; position:absolute;">
```

How can I set a div over another div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay one div over another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `z-index` on both and

and add style `relative` on `modal`
and `absolute` on `side nav bar`

and set `z-index` on `modal` as 0 and as 1 on `side nav bar`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `z-index` property.  Set a `z-index: 1` for the nav and set a higher z-index for the modal.

Comment: I would not change the `z-index` of the sidebar, as it could break others layers. Better check with the consoler developper the actual `z-index` of the sidebar, and increasing of 1 or 2 the value and set it for the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can give model z-index:1 then it will appear front.