# Disable links in an iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I am having troubles trying to disable links in an iframe. I am trying to create a transparent div that would overlay on top of the iframe so that links do not work. Anyone willing to help?

```html
<div id="framearea" style="border: 2px solid #000000; margin: 0px auto; width: 500px;">
<div id="framecover" style="position:absolute; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 100%"><img src="dot.gif" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
<iframe id="scoreboard" scrolling="no" src="http://www.espn.com" style="border: 2px solid; margin-left: 20px; height: 400px; margin-top: -170px; width: 312px; z-index: 1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: So where is your overlay `<div>`? you only have one `<div>` in your code which the `<iframe>` is inside it. there is no overlay `<div>`!

Comment: That is my issue. I tried to create one but cant get it to work.

Comment: OK, Please do some research before posting new questions. There are tons of solutions on the net that you can find by simply search for something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=html+css+overlay+div). Also [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) may help you...

Comment: @EhsanT, I have added the div for the overlay. The image for the overlay is a 1px x 1 px trasparent image that is stored locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have pointed previously, Using the accepted answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) will do what you want to do.

But to sum things up, I will use same code in that answer and change it a little to meet your needs:

```css
#container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

#framearea,
#framecover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#framearea{
  z-index: 1;
}

#framecover {
  z-index: 10;
}

#scoreboard{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="framearea">
    <iframe id="scoreboard" scrolling="no" src="https://www.godaddy.com"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="framecover">
    <img src="dot.gif" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

So you will have a `container`, then you have a `framearea` which your `<iframe>` will be in it and load you data inside it, then you will have a `framecover` which will be overlay using `z-index: 10;` css to bring it on top of `framearea` which has `z-index: 1;` css

**Update**

If you can not have separate `html` and `css` codes and should use `css` styles inside your `html` then the code above would be like this:

```html
<div id="container" style=" width: 700px; height: 700px; position: relative;">
  <div id="framearea" style="  width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;">
    <iframe id="scoreboard" scrolling="no" src="https://www.godaddy.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="framecover" style="  width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10;">
    <img src="dot.gif" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got my code to work using an online html/css tester. I need to combine that into just html as my CMS driven website does not allow css to be entered into a page element (as far as i can tell).

Comment: OK, then if this answer has helped you, please select it as accepter and give it an upvote.

Comment: There in lies my issues. I have tried to combine the html and css to no avail. And as you can tell, my coding abilities are very limited.

Comment: @Curt I have updated my answer and added a combined version as well

Comment: Thanks @EhsanT. When I run your code snippet, it works in the result window. Just curious how it would work when the "dot.gif" doesn't really exist.

Comment: :) you are welcome and nothing would happen if the `dot.gif` does not exist. as the matter of fact, right now in my code here, this images does not exists. so you can simple remove the `<img>` tag from the `<div id="framecover">` element. it still will work as you want.