# How to overlap multiple divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, gridview, e-commerce

I have 3 `div`s in a row and then again 3 `div`s in another row like a grid.

I want to overlap `div#4` on `div#1`,

[image: Over lay design]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible HTML and CSS example to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay one div over another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with one div having position absolute and other with position relative.

```
<div class="gray">

    <div class="blue">


    </div>
</div> 
.gray {
    background-color: #818181;

    height: 220px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #0090ff;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;

    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: To what point? Which value should be applied to which div? They're numbered, what div should be absolute and which should be relative? What position to give the parent?