# How to overlay a div over 2 others div with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of `<div>` like this:

```
<div>
    <div id='1'></div>
    <div id='2'></div>
    <div id='3'></div>
</div>
```

How can I create dynamically another div to cover `div#1` and `div#2` in JS or jQuery ?

```
<div id='event'>EVENT</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wrapAll` function provided by jQuery like

```js
$("#1, #2").wrapAll( "<div class='new' id='event'>EVENT</div>");
```

```css
.new{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div id='1'>1..</div>
    <div id='2'>2..</div>
    <div id='3'>3..</div>
</div>
```

The `.wrapAll()` function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in the set of matched elements, as a single group.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Mozilla's doc page, describing the outerHTML attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

After you get the parts of the code you want to wrap, reassign it with a `<div>` on the front side of 1 and a `</div>` on the back side of 2.

`d1 = document.getElementById('1');`

`d2 = document.getElementById('2');`

`d1.outerHTML = '<div>' + d1.outerHTML;`

`d2.outerHTML = d2.outerHTML + '</div>';`

Comment: Ah crud I misread. You only want to cover #1 and #2, not the outer one. Jumped the gun there, I'll try again.

Comment: There that should do it.