# Clickable info-box

Tags: javascript, function

How can I edit the JS (or CSS?) for this page (http://thepostrider.com/2018-senate-election/) in order to have the "info-box" stop glitching out, and make each state clickable so that the infobox pops up and you could read it until clicking off to another state?

Here is the JS:

```
    $("path, circle").click(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can change the position of info box as `absolute` instead of `relative`. When you do it, it will not affect the position of the remaining website. Then you will need to give correct coordinates to info box for positioning it on page.

[How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)

Here there is a detailed explanation in answers.

Comment: Okay it looks better now, I think that worked pretty well (http://thepostrider.com/2018-senate-election/) - but how can I make it "clickable", I think that's a JS requirement? They're all still hover over so I can't click on the links (for example for Wisconsin).