# Elements (React Components) with position: relative overlapping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

tl;dr: I'm finding that consecutive elements on my page with `position: relative` are overlapping, and really don't understand why.

Details: I'm trying to write a re-usable React component `SlidePair` that allows you to toggle between two other components with a slide animation, passing data between them. I'm using [react-reveal](https://www.react-reveal.com/docs/) for the animation, and positioning the elements at the same place in the page, so the exit of one accompanies the entry of the other. To make the divs overlap I followed the approach of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div).

My code, in the context of an `App.js` file from `create-react-app`, is below. You see that in the main `App` component I want to stack two `SlidePair` elements, which turn out to overlap instead. Everything else are just some example components for me to plug in; I've only included them for the sake of anyone who just wants to copy and paste the whole thing to get it running.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Slide from 'react-reveal/Slide';

class RedBox extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            text: props.text
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        const { toggleState, text, style} = this.props;
        return(

                <div style={style}
                     onClick={()=>{console.log('red clicked'); toggleState({text: this.state.text})}}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange}
                           type="text" value={this.state.text}
                           onClick={(event)=>{event.stopPropagation()}}
                            style={{zIndex: '999'}}
                    />
                    { text }
                </div>

        );
    }
}

const BlueBox = ({toggleState, passedProps, style })=> {
    return (
        <div onClick={toggleState} style={style}>
            { passedProps.text }
        </div>
    );
};

class MouseTracker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        const coords = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY
        };
        this.props.toggleState(coords);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100px' }} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <h1>Click me!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const MouseInformer = ({toggleState, passedProps}) => (
    <div>
        You clicked {passedProps.x}, {passedProps.y}!
        <button onClick={toggleState}>Go Back</button>
    </div>
);

class SlidePair extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { left: true, passedProps: {}};
        this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this);
    }

    toggleState(passedProps){
        const left = !this.state.left;
        console.log(`Toggling left to ${left}`);
        this.setState({ left, passedProps });
    }

    render(){
        const {left, passedProps } = this.state;
        return(
            <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
                 <Slide left when={left} >
                     <div style={ {position: 'absolute', top: '0px', right: '0px', width: '100%', zIndex: left ? '998' : -1 }}>
                        {this.props.renderLeft(this.toggleState, passedProps)}
                    </div>
                 </Slide>
                    <Slide right when={!left}>
                        <div style={{position: 'absolute', top: '0px', right: '0px', width: '100%', zIndex: left ?  -1 : 1}}>
                        { this.props.renderRight(this.toggleState, passedProps) }
                        </div>
                    </Slide>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends Component {

    render(){
        const redBox = (toggleState, passedProps)=>(
            <RedBox toggleState={toggleState}
                    style={{width: '100%', border: '5px solid red', height: '100px'}}/>
        );

        const blueBox = (toggleState, passedProps) => (
            <BlueBox
                toggleState={toggleState}
                passedProps={passedProps}
                style={{width: '100%', border: '5px solid blue', height: '100px'}}
            />
        );

        const mouseTracker = (toggleState, passedProps) => (
            <MouseTracker toggleState={toggleState} passedProps={passedProps} style={{top: '300px'}}/>
        );

        const mouseInformer = (toggleState, passedProps) => (
            <MouseInformer toggleState={toggleState} passedProps={passedProps} style={{top: '300px'}}/>
        );

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <SlidePair renderLeft={redBox} renderRight={blueBox}/>
                <br/>
                <SlidePair renderLeft={mouseTracker} renderRight={mouseInformer} />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Your component seems to be working fine.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sound-ydyzi

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox! The JS seems fine, yes. But the css is broken: I want two separate sliders, separated vertically by a <br/>, as in the App component layout. One should toggle between a red box and a blue one, with text from the red one passed to the blue; below that should be one where you click on it and it slides to something that reports the x, y coords of where you clicked. These components overlap. @ydyzi

Comment: Sorry, meant to tag @Dupocas