# Issues to create a fixed svg footer with text on it

Tags: css

I'm pretty new to code and I have some issues with my footer...
I don't know how to add text over it. It's either on top or bottom of my footer...

```css
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
  height: 77px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

footer h1 {
  font: 30px "Elastik-B";
  color: black;
  right:300px;
})
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer">






    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1670 97" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
</g>
</svg>
<h1>27.05.19</h1>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try adding `footer h1{position:absolute; top:0;` As I can see your footer already have a `right:300px` which means that the `position:absolute` must have been there before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)