# Bring element on top of modal backdrop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a guide functionality for my application. As a part of this functionality, it is expected that a tooltip is shown next to the target HTML element and this target element is brought on top of modal backdrop that appears together with the tooltip.

The problem is that after significant effort I still cannot make HTML element show on top of the modal backdrop. Simple tricks like `z-index: 10000 !important; position: relative` do not help. Also changing parent elements' `z-index` by disabling it in Firefox Developer Tools (and leaving `z-index: 10000 !important; position: relative` for the target element that is supposed to be on top of the modal backdrop)  does not help.

HTML of the application is quite complex with many elements. But I want to be able to "highlight" any given element by bringing it on top of the modal overlay knowing only its id. Is there an easy way to do that with JavaScript/React?

Hopefully there is a way to do this without modifying the DOM, which would be highly preferable.

**UPD:** [Code demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-z-index-yfc08) - press hat button to show guide/tooltips

Comment: I'm kind of in the same boat. Currently reading this stack post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div

Comment: Do you want to implement such a thing? https://introjs.com/

Comment: This is usually quite easy @altern but first could you share what you've already got please?

Comment: @AliYaghoubi: introjs looks really good, but I tried and it does not work for me - it is not possible to access HTML elements that are being highlighted. For example, I have a button that I want users to click and field to fill in, but they appear to be inaccessible

Comment: @altern Also you can use `Sweetalert`: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types

Comment: @AliYaghoubi: do not quite understand how `Sweetalert` (input-types) is relevant...

Comment: @sanepete: added link to codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the z-index from `.form-wrapper` and apply relative position with z-index for the targetted elements.

I did this by  adding

```
d.classList.add("tooltip-active-element");
```

to App.js@77

Also added the class to the css file:

```
.tooltip-active-element {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
}
```

and removed the z-index value from other classes, the key one being the `.form-wrapper` class.

Working demo:  https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-z-index-forked-fg9pt

[image]

Comment: I set a background color just to verify the correct element of tooltip, not needed for end results of course.

Comment: It does not work for the first step (#projectName input) for some reason. And I tried to recreate the desired behavior in my sandbox by applying all your recommendations - it does not work. Maybe you forgot to mention something else you did?

Comment: @altern compare my sandbos css file with yours, the issue just as mentioned is the z-index usage on elements. Also, first step isn't working because the class  isn't set properly on that, i just experimented with the next-step on tooltip functionality to bring fourth  a working **example**