# Although scripts and css included, Bootstrap modal popup won't work

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a simple popup with Bootstrap modal but I can't make it work and have no clue why... I've added all the latest [CSS and JS scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) and tried the example code from the [Bootstrap modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/), but nothing gives.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-XWTTruHZEYJsxV3W/lSXG1n3Q39YIWOstqvmFsdNEEQfHoZ6vm6E9GK2OrF6DSJSpIbRbi+Nn0WDPID9O7xB2Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Test
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-6UofPqm0QupIL0kzS/UIzekR73/luZdC6i/kXDbWnLOJoqwklBK6519iUnShaYceJ0y4FaiPtX/hRnV/X/xlUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-9GacT4119eY3AcosfWtHMsT5JyZudrexyEVzTBWV3viP/YfB9e2pEy3N7WXL3SV6ASXpTU0vzzSxsbfsuUH4sQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap Version 5.2 .
Since Bootstrap 5 all `data`-Attributes got added an `bs` forming all data-Attributes to for example `data-bs-target`.

You were using an older Documentation with the newer Bundle js.

It can be a little confusing as if you are searching for something with Bootstrap mostly you will be directed to Bootstrap 4 instead of Bootstrap 5.
So be careful which version you include and which version of Documentation you are reading.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-XWTTruHZEYJsxV3W/lSXG1n3Q39YIWOstqvmFsdNEEQfHoZ6vm6E9GK2OrF6DSJSpIbRbi+Nn0WDPID9O7xB2Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalLong">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Test
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-6UofPqm0QupIL0kzS/UIzekR73/luZdC6i/kXDbWnLOJoqwklBK6519iUnShaYceJ0y4FaiPtX/hRnV/X/xlUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-9GacT4119eY3AcosfWtHMsT5JyZudrexyEVzTBWV3viP/YfB9e2pEy3N7WXL3SV6ASXpTU0vzzSxsbfsuUH4sQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is some BS if you ask me... sorry it was too tempting :)
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, i've came across this BS multiple times now. The Reason why you would be directed to BS4 while searching instead of BS5 is, that BS5 wasn't stable enough for production usage.

Answer (score 0):

### use data-bs-target

Instead of using data-target you should use data-bs-target beacuse you are using
bootstrtap 5