# How to stack relative positioned divs?

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem: I have a `div` tag and images of 100px width each on both sides of the `div`. Now I want to add a number of div `tags` stacked over each other in the middle of it and they have to be  fluid (using % width) and relative to support multiple resolutions. How can I do it?

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/yTkaP/1/)

Comment: negative `margin`s and positive `z-index`es applied to the elements you want to overlay? Also, don't forget that you can place an element with `position: absolute` inside an element with `position: relative` and it can be placed absolutely within its parent without affecting the positioning of its relatively-positioned siblings.

Comment: Difficult to answer without any code, but if you want to overlay divs they should be position:absolute with different top left for each

Comment: Actually i am using margin-right:100px and margin-left:100px,if i use absolute i get undesired effect and if i use relative positioning the space that was actually being used by those divs will be blank.

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code, can't picture what you need just with that.

Comment: what do you want the other divs to overlay? Do you want them to just overlay the center div or the center div and the image divs?

Comment: i want all the center divs to be displayed one over the other so that i can selectively show them later using opacity...i want the center1,2,3,4 to be in the center of content 'div' overlayed on each other. And the width should be 100% - 100px on each side...i hope you get me

Comment: yes, that's not overlay, that's one on top of the other or stacked as you said :)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1909682/1034619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do that with the center being `position: relative` is by knowing the `height` of the center divs and adjusting `margin-bottom` of the div immediately above. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/XMkDt/10/ (this is only a single line, not very useful), and http://jsfiddle.net/XMkDt/26/ (this is equal height divs, but could be adapted to accommodate different heights; note: on my FF win7 the border's align correctly but the text is tweaked by a pixel and I'm not sure why--but for your purposes, it would work).

Note: you would want to make sure `z-index: 1` was set to the div that you are actually showing at the time (as you make your opacity change), to lift it above the other divs.

Comment: good answer, I didn't know height was all it took to put relative in relative

Comment: Well, its not just the height, its knowing that so you can offset it the correct distance with the bottom margin.

Comment: As relative keeps the space for the element at the original position,wont that change the positioning of the following divs??

Comment: No, because the div is not being moved relative to itself (as when you do `top: -100px` or some such) this leaves the "gap" where the element was "inflow." By using just negative margin, it is moving the whole relative element as a unit (the div's could be `static` and it would function just the same, but you want `relative` most likely so you can set a `z-index` on the elements).

Comment: thanks for the answer,but can you please tell on what basis the -222px value was decided,will surely clear my concept.

Comment: In my example it is the height (200px) + padding (top and bottom of 10px each) + border width (top and bottom of 1px each).

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BXW8y/)? You'll need a hell of a lot of empty spaces though to make them fill the width...

EDIT:

New fiddle with fluid width: http://jsfiddle.net/BXW8y/1/

Comment: The problem that i wanted solution for still persists in your answer.If i decrease the width of browser the center div gets behind the right image rather than being fluid and adjusting.

Comment: no it doesn't - at least not if i add some extra spaces between the &nbsp;'s http://jsfiddle.net/BXW8y/1/