# how i do make this rotating cube more responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here am taking one cube from net which is rotating. This is my [`similar`](http://jsfiddle.net/46efsqeh/1/) code.

Now am trying to do like if i reduce browser size, then table size and cube size should reduce. I mean they should be at same place. not like cube in next line to table as in example.

They both should be side by side for any browser size .

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you are asking to have the cube on top of the table ?

If so, then you should learn about having your main div

```
position:relative;
```

and have a wrapper div

```
position:absolute;
```

Example taken from [Stacking DIVs on top of each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909648/stacking-divs-on-top-of-each-other)

```
<style type="text/css">
.inner {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">1</div>
   <div class="inner">2</div>
   <div class="inner">3</div>
   <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

Cheers, 
Demetry