# Three Divs on Top of Each-Other Within Left Column - No Bootstrap - HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, multiple-columns

I'm having trouble trying to stack three divs on top of each-other within a left-column div. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm attempting to use the solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909648/stacking-divs-on-top-of-each-other), so I have this:

```css
.main-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main-div-line-1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-div-line-2 {
    display: flex;
}

/*parent*/
.inner-main-left {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-top {
    position: absolute;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-middle {
    position: absolute;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}

.inner-main-right {
    display: flex;
}

#main-kitty-image {
    width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="main-div-line-1">
    Kitty Averages
  </div>
  <div class="main-div-line-2">
    <div class="inner-main-left">
      <div class="inner-left-left-top">
        helloKitty Top
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left-left-middle">
        helloKitty Middle
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left-left-bottom">
        helloKitty Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-main-right">
      <img id="main-kitty-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/JmY6X13.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isn't the idea to have the parent div, in this case, `inner-main-left` as `position: relative` and then the inner divs, `inner-left-left-top`, `inner-left-left-middle` and `inner-left-left-bottom`, each as `position: absolute`?

`.inner-main-left` and `.inner-main-right` are both children of `.main-div-line-2`. We want those two side by side, which is why I'm displaying them both as `flex`. But that shouldn't alter their ability to stack divs on top-of each-other within them, right?

If you run the snippet above or visit [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kuev4qsb/), you'll see that this is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed out in the article that @Paulie_D linked, the key is to add `flex-direction: column` to the div that you want to act as a parent column.

Then for the children within that div, you can set `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` like this:

```
    .inner-left-left-top {
       flex: 0 0 100px;
    }

    .inner-left-left-middle {
        flex: 0 0 100px;
    }

    .inner-left-left-bottom {
        flex: 0 0 100px;
    }
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kuev4qsb/10/) and see [MDN Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Answer (score 1):

I have configured the flex according to your desired layout. You may refer to w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) for more info.

```css
.main-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main-div-line-1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-div-line-2 {
    display: flex;
}

/*parent*/
.inner-main-left {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-top {
    flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-middle {
    flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}
/*child*/
.inner-left-left-bottom {
    flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}

.inner-main-right {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 50%;
}

#main-kitty-image {
    width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="main-div-line-1">
    Kitty Averages
  </div>
  <div class="main-div-line-2">
    <div class="inner-main-left">
      <div class="inner-left-left-top">
        helloKitty Top
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left-left-middle">
        helloKitty Middle
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left-left-bottom">
        helloKitty Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-main-right">
      <img id="main-kitty-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/JmY6X13.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```